# Django filter on relational data

Tags: django, django-models

I defined some models in Django with relationships. When I want to get data by filtering relation data I got error.

Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    UserId = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    Username = models.CharField()
    RelatedPerson = models.ForeignKey(
        People,
        db_column='PersonId',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

class Staff(models.Model):
    RelatedUser = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='StaffUserId',
        related_name='RelatedUser'
    )
```

My query is this:

```
staff = Staff.objects.filter(RelatedUser__UserId=user_id).first()
```

I also tried to get with other field which is not primary key and it didn't work too:

```
staff = Staff.objects.filter(RelatedUser__UserId=user_id).first()
```

And this is the error I get :

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'id'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driv
er 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Comment: It looks like you did not fully migrated your models, since your `UserId` is the primary key, you can however use `Staff.objects.filter(RelatedUser_id=user_id).first()`.

Comment: Yes, I didn't deliberately. because I am trying to create a wrapper on my existing database.

Comment: it looks like you probably should specify for `UserId = models.CharField(db_column='UserId', ...)`.

Comment: Actually I did it. It didn't work. I tried to get by other field like ```username``` but it doesn't work too.

Comment: well there clearly is a mismatch between the `User` table in your database and the Django model, so I propose that you take a look whether the fields match.